# In python Sorting a list of tuples?

Tags: python, sorting

How do you sort a list by elemant thats a  tuple? 
Let say below is the list LL.
I want to sort ID2 -- LL[1]  which is a tuple as asc. 
How would I do it.

```
           Id,  Id2    CCC
           A123 A120 '2011-03'
  LL=      A133 A123 '2011-03'
           D123 D120 '2011-04'
           D140 D123 '2011-04'
```

Comment: `ID2 -- LL[1] which is a tuple as asc` - *what*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/

`sorted(LL, key=itemgetter(1))` might do what you want.

Please note that you have to `from operator import itemgetter` to get the `itemgetter` function.

```
In [1]: LL = (('A123', 'A120', '2011-03'), ('A133', 'A123', '2011-03'), ('D123', 'D120', '2011-04'), ('D140', 'D123', '2011-04'))

In [2]: from operator import itemgetter

In [3]: sorted(LL, key=itemgetter(1))
Out[3]:
[('A123', 'A120', '2011-03'),
 ('A133', 'A123', '2011-03'),
 ('D123', 'D120', '2011-04'),
 ('D140', 'D123', '2011-04')]
```

Comment: Does it matter that key=itemgetter(1) is a tuple

Comment: `key=itemgetter(1)` will make `sorted()` fetch the item with index 1 from each element in `LL`. Please actually read the page I linked to, it explains it: http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Operator_Module_Functions

Comment: I have been trying to figure this out for a while . I found my prob. The database has the sorted col as Primary Key which keeps changing my order. ;-)))))! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can go for:

```
LL.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])
```

Where 1 is the index of the element of the tupple.

Comment: Better use `itemgetter(1)` from the `operator` module. Otherwise a python function needs to be called for every item (the `operator` functions are written in C if you are using the default CPython implementation)